# While Accessing SD card Error (No such file or directory)" File is available as shown in screenshot of Device File Explorer

Tags: android

In Android Studio 3.5.3 while Accessing SD card I receive message Error message "/storage/sdcard0/Download/ExpenseManager.db (No such file or directory)" 
But File is available as shown in screenshot of Device File Explorer

```
try {
    if(ExternalStorageUtil.isExternalStorageMounted()) {

        // Check whether this app has write external storage permission or not.
        int writeExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ExternalStorageActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        // If do not grant write external storage permission.
        if(writeExternalStoragePermission!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // Request user to grant write external storage permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ExternalStorageActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
        }else {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            String currentDBPath = "/data/com.starexpensemanager/databases/";
            String backupDBPath = "/storage/sdcard0/Download/ExpenseManager.db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File("/", backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Restored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save to public external storage failed. Error message is " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

[image: Device File Explorer]

I receive error in Line 
FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();

Comment: Never hardcode paths. Paths that you as a developer see in Device File Explorer will not necessarily match the paths that your app is able to use. Always assemble filesystem paths using methods on `Context` or `Environment` to get the base directories for different storage locations.

Comment: Your observation is correct, but Hardcode paths are for testing only. So that I don't have to check variable values every time.